# On-line citations for Physical Review B documents in REVTeX

Tags: citing, revtex

At some point the Physical Review B journal switched from superscript citations to on-line citations. However, when I prepare a document using `\documentclass[aps,prb,reprint]{revtex4-1}`, I still get superscript citations. Should I have to change anything to get on-line citations? (Surely I don't have to use `\onlinecite{<key>}` everywhere?)

As far as I can tell, I'm using the latest version of REVTeX. It's from latest `texlive-publishers` package for Ubuntu. As far as I can tell, the files in that package are the same as in the official revtex4-1 zip file.

EDIT: minimum example below.

The TeX file:

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\begin{document}

Arg! \cite{Landau_Elasticity}

\bibliography{da_bib}

\end{document}
```

The bib file (da_bib.bib):

```
@book{Landau_Elasticity,
    title = {Theory of Elasticity},
    author = {L.D. Landau and E.M. Lifshitz},
    isbn = {978-0750626330},
    year = {1986},
    publisher = {Pergamon Press}
}
```

EDIT 2: I decided to email APS (the REVTeX maintainers), and the short answer is that it'll be fixed in REVTeX 4.2:

> Thank you for writing. When using "prb" as a documentclass option, the
>   output will show superscript citation numbers. However, should your
>   manuscript be  accepted for publication, our production vendor will
>   change the superscript to square bracket citations.
>
> This will be updated in the next REVTeX4.2 release, and the
>   documentation  will also be updated.
>
> We appreciate your cooperation. Let us know if you have any further
>   concerns.

Comment: Can you show a minimal example?

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the class code documentation, “PRB requires superscript citations”. If you want to override the choice, reset `\bibpunct`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Landau_Elasticity,
    title = {Theory of Elasticity},
    author = {L.D. Landau and E.M. Lifshitz},
    isbn = {978-0750626330},
    year = {1986},
    publisher = {Pergamon Press}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[aps,prb,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\bibpunct{[}{]}{;}{n}{}{}


\begin{document}

Arg! \cite{Landau_Elasticity}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I guess APS simply hasn't updated REVTeX since they changed the PRB style ("References and footnotes... should be designated and cited in text by on-line Arabic numerals in square brackets." http://journals.aps.org/prb/info/infoB.html ), which is annoying.

Comment: Yup, they simply haven't updated REVTeX yet. I've added an email from APS to my original question.